# Prove that $3^n > 3n$ for integer $n\geq2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function, binomial-theorem, formal-proofs

How would we prove, by contradiction that  $3^n > 3n$ for integer $n\geq2$. I'm having trouble on where I should start in tackling this question.

I know that we should first state the negative of the statement, ie, 
we assume $3^n \leq 3n$ for integer $n\geq2$, but I am not sure how to prove this assumption wrong.

Comment: Induction is the traditional approach. To get from $3^n$ to $3^{n+1}$ you need to multiply by $3$, but to get from $3n$ to $3(n+1)$ you need to add $3$.

Comment: For this type of question I would suggest using induction. However if you are set on proving by contradiction, the proof would start along the lines of "Suppose not. Then for $n\geq2$, $3^{n}\leq 3n$." Can you go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $3^n\leq3n$ for some $n\geq2$.

Thus,
$$3^n=(1+2)^n\geq1+2n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot4>3n,$$
which is contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge1$, Bernoulli's Inequality gives
$$
\begin{align}
3^{n-1}
&=(1+2)^{n-1}\\
&\ge1+2(n-1)\\
&=2n-1\\
&\ge n\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $3$ yields
$$
3^n\ge3n\tag2
$$